# What is this font? The word "Fall" Specifically

Tags: fonts

[image]

What is this font? The word "Fall" Specifically.

Answer (score 4):

It's Gravitas One

[image]

The hatch fill probably is added in a vector drawing software. It can have any fill pattern and it can be used to mask anything.

[image]

Comment: @AshleySampson but, press the accept button, too.